# Running Totals Skipping Over Certain Values

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate a column that has a value column subtracted from a Total column but can skip rows until it can no longer find a smaller value.  The sequence relates to dates so the order must be preserved. The value (Need) cannot be larger than the total as those are deleted prior.

This is for SQL Server 2016.  My initial thought process was to use window functions and a running total, but I cannot figure out how to skip the 400 and continue to the 2 rows below. I included my attempts in the CASE statement as TransferQty and the running total as ReferenceCol.

Code to reproduce:

```sql
DECLARE @i TABLE
(
    sequence INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Total INT
    ,Need INT
)
INSERT INTO @i 
VALUES (500,100)
,(500,200)
,(500,50)
,(500,400)
,(500,50)
,(500,50)

SELECT 
     sequence
    ,Total
    ,Need
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Total - SUM(Need) OVER (ORDER BY sequence) > 0 
        THEN Need 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS TransferQty
    ,Total - SUM(Need) OVER (ORDER BY sequence) as ReferenceCol
FROM @i
```

Current Results

```
+----------+-------+------+-------------+--------------+
| Sequence | Total | Need | TransferQty | ReferenceCol |
+----------+-------+------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 |   500 |  100 |         100 |          400 |
|        2 |   500 |  200 |         200 |          200 |
|        3 |   500 |   50 |          50 |          150 |
|        4 |   500 |  400 |           0 |         -250 |
|        5 |   500 |   50 |           0 |         -300 |
|        6 |   500 |   50 |           0 |         -350 |
+----------+-------+------+-------------+--------------+
```

Desired Results

```
+----------+-------+------+-------------+--------------+
| Sequence | Total | Need | TransferQty | ReferenceCol |
+----------+-------+------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 |   500 |  100 |         100 |          400 |
|        2 |   500 |  200 |         200 |          200 |
|        3 |   500 |   50 |          50 |          150 |
|        4 |   500 |  400 |           0 |          150 | --skip calc
|        5 |   500 |   50 |          50 |          100 |
|        6 |   500 |   50 |          50 |           50 |
+----------+-------+------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Would you be interested on the [Quirky Update](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/)?

Comment: @LuisCazares Thank you.  I was able to perform the calculation needed using that method.  It isn't pretty and requires specific rules, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this code if you have a single skip, but when you have multi skips then you have to loop through and perform the delete of record based on the existence of rolling value exceeding the total.

```
        DECLARE @i TABLE
        (
            sequence INT IDENTITY(1,1)
            ,Total INT
            ,Need INT
        )
        INSERT INTO @i 
        VALUES 
         (500,100    )
        ,(500,200   )
        ,(500,50    )
        ,(500,400   )
        ,(500,50    )
        ,(500,50    )

        select  sequence,Total,Need 
        into    #temp_original 
        from    @i

        select  
        b.sequence,b.Total, SUM( a.need) rollingvalue , 
                case when  SUM( a.need) > b.Total 
                        then 0
                     when SUM( a.need) =  b.Total   then SUM( a.need)
                    else b.Total - SUM( a.need)  end  how_much_needed
        into    #temp
        from    @i a
        join    @i b
                on a.sequence < b.sequence + 1
        group by b.sequence,b.Total


        delete from a 
        from    @i a
        join    (
                    select min(sequence) min_sequence
                    from    #temp 
                    where  how_much_needed = 0
                ) minseq
                on minseq.min_sequence = a.sequence


        select  
        b.sequence,b.Total, SUM( a.need) rollingvalue , 
                case when  SUM( a.need) > b.Total 
                        then 0
                     when SUM( a.need) =  b.Total   then SUM( a.need)
                    else b.Total - SUM( a.need)  end  how_much_needed
        into    #temp2
        from    @i a
        join    @i b
                on a.sequence < b.sequence + 1
        group by b.sequence,b.Total

        select   a.sequence,a.Total,a.Need, case when  isnull (b.rollingvalue , 0) = 0 then 0 else case when b.rollingvalue > a.Total then 0 else  a.Need end end as TransferQty  , ISNULL( case when  b.how_much_needed = b.Total then a.Need else b.how_much_needed end,  case when ( select how_much_needed from #temp2 where sequence = a.sequence -1) = a.Total then 0 else (select how_much_needed from #temp where sequence = a.sequence -1) end )  ReferenceCol 
        from    #temp_original a
        LEFT join   #temp2 b
                on a.sequence = b.sequence
        join    #temp c
                on c.sequence = a.sequence

        drop table #temp
        drop table #temp2
        drop table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I went with which is based off of the "Quirky Update" from the original comment.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #i
GO

CREATE TABLE #i 
(
    sequence INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Total INT
    ,Need INT
    ,RunningTransfer INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #i 
VALUES 
 (500,100,NULL)
,(500,200,NULL)
,(500,50,NULL)
,(500,400,NULL)
,(500,50,NULL)
,(500,50,NULL)
,(500,100,NULL)
,(500,49,NULL)
,(500,50,NULL)

DECLARE @TransferRunningTotal INT

UPDATE #i
    SET @TransferRunningTotal = RunningTransfer = CASE 
                                                    --this skips values larger than running total
                                                    WHEN @TransferRunningTotal < Need THEN @TransferRunningTotal 
                                                    --this creates the running total
                                                    WHEN @TransferRunningTotal > Need THEN @TransferRunningTotal - Need 
                                                    --creates the initial value
                                                    ELSE Total - Need 
                                                 END
FROM #i WITH (TABLOCKX)
 OPTION (MAXDOP 1) 

SELECT sequence
      ,Total
      ,Need
      ,CASE 
            WHEN need <= RunningTransfer THEN Need
            ELSE 0 
      END AS TsfQty
      ,RunningTransfer 
FROM #i
```